# Texmaker "click to jump to the line" does not always update in PDF viewer

Tags: pdftex, texmaker

I use Texmaker to edit my tex documents and I have the PDF viewer embedded in the editor, so I can edit the .tex files in the left and see the PDF result in the right. For big documents, a quite common Texmaker feature I use is "click to jump to the line" [Ctrl+click], that allows me to click somewhere in the PDF and it will direct to the specific line in the .tex file.

However, from time to time, this feature doesn't get updated with the PDF and redirects me to different (not far) parts of the document. I haven't been able to isolate the reason if it happening. I was wondering if this is just a bug or if there is an specific reason for this to happen (e.g. corrupt aux file?).

I am running Texmaker 4.2 (compiled with Qt 5.2.1 and Poppler 0.22.5) in a Windows 8 x64 machine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with version 4.#.# in Windows 10, however after an upgrade to version 5.0.2, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Windows10. Just make sure any folder in the whole path do not contain spaces and/or special characters (including the .tex file).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes and no. If it contains spaces it will never work, but when it doesnt, sometimes, it just stops working.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that I had this problem due to the fact that my folder was in OneDrive. Once I pulled it out of there, everything fell into place. But this works only if your file does not consist of many files.