# Toggle focus between Texmaker 4.5 and pdf viewer

Tags: pdf, texmaker, editors

There is a shortcut that enables one to directly jump from the editor of Texmaker 4.5 to the `.pdf` file and vise versa.

```
Ctrl+space : editor --->  .pdf
Ctrl+click : .pdf   --->  editor
```

When the above are used you are directed to the exact paragraph that you have selected. `Ctrl+Space`, additionally, briefly highlights that specific paragraph with a red box.

However, this does not always work properly and instead you are directed at the top of the current page or not working at all. Is this a bug or a feature and how can one ensure that this always works?

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: I write in Texmaker 4.5.

Comment: This seems related (but maybe isn't a duplicate) to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224010/texmaker-click-to-jump-to-the-line-does-not-always-update-in-pdf-viewer

Comment: It is actually a somewhat different problem, but concerning the same feature of Latex.

No answers there, too!